# Is AMD Radeon graphics card supported with Blender 2.90 on Mac?

Tags: rendering

I got started on Blender last September. I bought a Mac 3.8 GHz Intel Core i7 8 cores, 32 GB 2667 MHz DDR4, with AMD Radeon Pro 5500 XT 8 GB graphics card. I am using version 2.90 of Blender and unfortunately with the Cycles render mode, AMD Radeon cards are not supported. The rendering execution time is therefore longer. Do you know if Blender will adjust this in future releases. Do you advise me instead to switch to Windows to have a compatible graphics card.

Comment: Radeon cards _are_ supported in blender (though admittedly have more issues than nvidia cards) - some of the most recent problems relate to the latest Adrenalin Drivers. Rolling back to an older driver version fixes this for many people. However, you are using a mac, which complicates things slightly. I understand mac uses Metal for a graphics API as opposed to OpenGL or DirectX, which might be responsible for some of the problems you are having. Blender is built upon OpenGL, and is DirectX compatible, but  I don't think it supports Metal at this time.

Comment: I have tried AMD ProRender and I don't know why but it was not faster at all.  Considering that Blender is built upon OpenGL and DirectX and considering that since I discovered last September Blender (during covid 19) and I love so much this App. I will sale my new Mac(2020)and buy a more compatible computer and operating system whatever the price. Does anyone could suggest me a product? 

A big thank!

Andre

Comment: Apple joined the Blender Development fund recently, and if you've heard about it, the new M1 Macs have GPU support. Now, the Intel-based Macs are under development, and like me, you are one of those people waiting for the release. Blender 3.1 is scheduled to release in March, so the beta version is coming sometime soon.

Answer (score 1):

Preferences > System > Cycles Render Devices and select OpenCL. You can also try AMD ProRender: https://www.amd.com/en/technologies/radeon-prorender-blender